# `Cannot read property 'document' of undefined` when `vue-cli-service build` (Webpack) with d3.js?

Tags: google-app-engine, d3.js, vue.js

I'm using GAE SE and `@vue/cli-service 3.0.1` .

When deploying the app, I execute `vue-cli-service build --modern` and serve the output in GAE SE. My app.yaml looks like this:

```
...
- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  application_readable: true

- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css
  application_readable: true

- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js
  application_readable: true
...
```

When I see the site in browser, nothing is rendered and in the console it says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined

```
  var d3 = {
    version: "3.5.17"
  };
  var d3_arraySlice = [].slice, d3_array = function(list) {
    return d3_arraySlice.call(list);
  };
  var d3_document = this.document; // Error is here
  function d3_documentElement(node) {
    return node && (node.ownerDocument || node.document || node).documentElement;
  }
```

One of the libs I use depends on `D3.js`, and the error is related to it.

There is nothing wrong when doing `vue-cli-service serve` in local environment.

How to make d3.js work in production environment ?

Comment: What is `this` in that context? Where does that code snippet run?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have a full answer, but this.document doesn't work because 'this' refers to the vue-object. You have to reference the Dom directly.

You can use one of these options:

- without 'this': var d3_document = document;
- this.$el;
- this.refs (in combination with setting the ref
  https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref & https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-refs)